# Overlapping columns in highchart

Tags: highcharts

Is there a way to create overlapping columns?

For example in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/67BkD/2/), the blue and the red columns should overlap each other as shown below, with the blue being the one at the back and red in front.

[image: Overlapping columns]

To clarify, I don't want stacked columns, both the blue and red columns should start from the xAxis (y=0) and not one over the other

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/new-question-asker-features/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**EDIT**
Highcharts has introduced [plotOptions.column.grouping](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.grouping) switch in their version 2.3 to handle exactly this. Refer [Garrick's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14368441/1566575)

I will leave below answer as it still helps understand how the groupPadding and pointWidth work.

**Original Answer**

You are looking for [grouped and overlapping columns](http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/67BkD/)?

You can achieve this by setting [plotOptions.column.groupPadding](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.column.groupPadding) to 0.5

```
plotOptions: {
    column: {           
        groupPadding: 0.5   // Exactly overlap
        pointWidth: 20,                                     
    }
},
```

Here's an image to illustrate how groupPadding works
[image: Group Padding]

As you see, when groupPadding is 0.5 the column width is compromised to give the desired padding, by specifying the pointWidth you can counter this behavior

Comment: I want the columns to be overlapping instead of stacked on top of one another. The pointPadding: -0.3 is close to what I want. Columns are overlapping but are not perfectly aligning. Any way to get them to align perfectly?

Comment: I am not sure about that @Armin, But wouldn't completely overlapping columns, totally eclipse the column at the back if the front column had a higher value?

Comment: It would, but the front column can never have a higher value, thats why I would want it that way :)

Comment: groupPadding + pointWidth did the trick. Its exactly what I wanted :). Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 30):

You can also accomplish this by setting `grouping: false`.

http://jsfiddle.net/garrickcheung/67BkD/19/

Comment: Agreed, seems somewhat cleaner solution.

Comment: Exactly the answer I was looking for

Comment: Great find, this did not work with version <=2.2, looks like they fixed it from version 2.3 onwards, 2.2 @ http://jsfiddle.net/67BkD/104/ 2.3 @ http://jsfiddle.net/67BkD/105/

Comment: I have a column 0-10 on y-axis, it has 2 values. 0-6 is colored in black, 2-10 is colored in green. So in this, 2-6 is shared portion. I want to make both the colors (black and green) visible by making the transparent. Is there any way to achieve this in highchart ?